# Windows: select and copy mp3 failes based on star rating

Tags: windows, mp3

I have a structured path of folders (main->band name->album->mp3 files) and all of those mp3 have a rating from 1 to 5 stars wrote inside themself. I have windows 7 and i can see the rating from explorer. I need a script that starting from the root of this structure, can find all the files with 5 or 4 stars and copy them to another place, keeping the same tree structure. On the destination folder at the end i will have exactly the same path structure, but containing only the 5 and 4 star rated mp3.
Can i do this with a .bat file or a .vbs script? Or Windows can show the ratings but cannot use them for selection, so i have to find another way? And if so, do you have any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is not powerful enough, but you may be able to use VBS by reading the [`System.Rating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787554%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) property via the [`ShellFolderItem.ExtendedProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774055%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) method. I've never done it myself, but I think those will get you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

By writing a new value to the **FileName** and/or **Directory** tags, files can be renamed and/or moved to different directories. This can be a very powerful tool in combination with the -d (date format) option for organizing images by date/time. For example, the following command renames all images in directory "DIR" according to the individual file's creation date in the form "`YYYYmmdd_HHMMSS.ext`".

```
exiftool "-FileName<CreateDate" -d "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S.%%e" DIR
```

Or a new directory can be specified by setting the value of the **Directory** tag. For example, the following command moves all images originally in directory "DIR" into a directory hierarchy organized by year/month/day:

```
exiftool "-Directory<DateTimeOriginal" -d "%Y/%m/%d" DIR
```

([source](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/#filename))

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. Please try to include at least summary of information you are linking to.